# Asymptotic inversion of ExpIntegralEi function

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, series-expansion, asymptotics

I'm looking at the small-x and large-x asymptotic expansions of the inverse of exponential integral $E_1$ (https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2#E1)

$$\begin{array}{lll}
E_1 & = & \int_z^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm{d}t\\
E_{1\text{small}}^{ - 1} (x) &\sim&  - \log x - \log ( - \log x) - \frac{{\log ( - \log x) - 1}}{{\log x}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{(\log ( - \log x))^2 }}{{\log ^2 x}}} \right)\\
E_{1\text{large}}^{ - 1} (x) &\sim&  e^{ - x - \gamma }  + e^{ - 2x - 2\gamma }  + \frac{5}{4}e^{ - 3x - 3\gamma }  +  \cdots 
\end{array}
$$

Gergo Nemes derived them by hand [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180259/behavior-of-inverse-of-fs-frac1h-n-sum-i-1n-left1-frac1i-right/4192757#comment8699044_4192757):

> I expressed −−1()  via
> [dlmf.nist.gov/6.6.E2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.6#E2), took the
> exponential of both sides, expanded the exponential of the power
> series and finally employed series reversion to solve for

I'm interested in improving these expansions by adding terms and generally learning how to automate the process. What is the most elegant way to do this in Mathematica?

```
E1[z_] := -ExpIntegralEi[-z]; (* https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2#E1 *)

E1inv[y_] := x /. First@Flatten@Solve[{E1[x] == y, x > 0}, x];
E1invSmall[x_] := -Log[x] - Log[-Log[x]] - (Log[-Log[x]] - 1)/
  Log[x];(* + O(Log[-Log[x]]^2/Log[x]^2)*)
E1invLarge[x_] := 
 Exp[-x - EulerGamma] + Exp[-2 x - 2 EulerGamma] + 
  5/4 Exp[-3 x - 3 EulerGamma];

Plot[{E1inv[y], E1invSmall[y], E1invLarge[y]}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Approximating \!\(\*SubscriptBox[SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-1\)], \
\(1\)]\)", 
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-1\)], \
\(1\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[SubscriptBox[SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-1\)], \
\(1\)], \(small\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[SubscriptBox[SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-1\)], \
\(1\)], \(large\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

**edit July 21**

Large x expansion:

```
E1[z_] := EulerGamma - ExpIntegralEi[-z];
series1 = Series[E1[z], {z, 0, 4}, Assumptions -> z > 0] // Normal;
result = InverseSeries@Series[Exp[series1], {z, 0, 4}] // Normal;
result /. (z -> Exp[z + EulerGamma]) // TraditionalForm
```

$$\frac{907}{240} e^{-6 z-6 \gamma }+\frac{361}{144} e^{-5 z-5 \gamma }+\frac{31}{18} e^{-4 z-4 \gamma }+\frac{5}{4} e^{-3 z-3 \gamma }+e^{-2 z-2 \gamma }+e^{-z-\gamma }$$

Comment: On the obvious track `E1[z_] = -ExpIntegralEi[-z];  E1inv = InverseFunction[E1];  Series[E1inv[x], {x, 0, 3}]` I get a result that is definitely wrong (hitting a wrong branch?).

Comment: Also plotting InverseFunction[E1] gives a weird discontinuous plot

Comment: May be variable substitution of the original integral definition of E1 helps a litte:`........................................ t ->Log[x] ` yields `Integrate[1/(x Log[x]) 1/x, {x, E^z, Infinity}, Assumptions -> z > 0] `  and then  x- -> Log[r] yields `Integrate[1/(Log[r]^2 Log[Log[r]]) 1/r, {r, E^E^z, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> z > 0] `  both forms are equal to `-ExpIntegralEi[-z] `

Comment: Your function fulfills `f'[x] == f[x] Exp[-f[x]]`. Maybe it would be helpful somehow

Comment: The recipe is known (I added in the edit), I was more interested in how to do the algebraic steps in Mathematica, how to 1) expand exponential of the power series and 2) use series reversion to solve for z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got correct hints on Math.SE. Define:

```
E1[z_] := EulerGamma - ExpIntegralEi[-z];
E2[z_] := -ExpIntegralEi[-z] Exp[z];
```

They can be inverted like this

```
Series[E1[z], {z, 0, 4}, Assumptions -> z > 0]
(*-Log[z]+z-z^2/4+z^3/18-z^4/96+O[z]^5*)
InverseSeries[Series[Exp[z - z^2/4 + z^3/18 - z^4/96], {z, 0, 4}]/z]
(*1/z+(1/z)^2+5/(4 z^3)+31/(18 z^4)+361/(144 z^5)+O[1/z]^7*)
```

Some plot for the confirmation

```
ParametricPlot[{{E1[z], z}, {z, E1[z]}, 
 {z, Log[Exp[z - z^2/4 + z^3/18 - z^4/96]/z]}, 
 {Log[z],1/z + (1/z)^2 + 5/(4 z^3) + 31/(18 z^4) + 361/(144 z^5)}, 
 {z, (361 E^(-5 z))/144 + (31 E^(-4 z))/18 + (5 E^(-3 z))/4 + E^(-2 z) +
     E^-z}}, 
 {z, 0.01, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}]
```

Now let us focus on the other limit. `E2` has a nice series expansion at infinity

```
s2 = Series[E2[x], {x, Infinity, 1}]
```

$$ \frac{1}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

The dominant decay of `E1` at large values of `z` comes therefore from the exponent---seek the solution in the form

$$z= -\log(y)+u(y).$$

Substitute this in the defining series expansion of `E1`. We get an equation of the form

$$e^u=\text{rational function of $u$}.$$

For instance, to the leading order we have

$$e^{u_0}=\frac{1}{\log(z)}.$$

Determine $u_0$, substitute back, determine the next term $u_1$, iterate.

Comment: Hm, I wonder why that expansion looks so different from the expression in math.SE post

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov  As far as I can see it looks the same `(361 E^(-5 z))/144 + (31 E^(-4 z))/18 + (5 E^(-3 z))/4 + E^(-2 z) + E^-z` and even more terms... I skipped some trivial substitutions :)

Comment: thanks, it works for Einvlarge....what do you mean by treated similarly for E2? `InverseSeries` command returns unevaluated if I just follow through the same steps