# Getting a series expansion for implicitly defined function

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have a function $f(r)$ defined as $x$ satisfying $g(r,x)=0$.

How do I get a series expansion of $f(r)$ around $r=\infty$?

Function $f(r)$ below is unexpectedly linear, and I'm trying to get a closed form expression for exact values of slope and intercept

```
ClearAll["Globals`*"];
g[r_, x_] = 
  Log[2 (-(E^x)^(-1/r) r + Zeta[1 + 1/r])^2 Zeta[2 (1 + 1/r)]] - 
   Log[Zeta[
      1 + 1/r]^2 (-((E^x)^(1 - 2 (1 + 1/r))/(-1 + 2 (1 + 1/r))) + 
       Zeta[2 (1 + 1/r)])];
f[r_] := x /. FindRoot[g[r, x], {x, 1}];
Plot[f[r], {r, 1, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"r", "f(r)"}]
```

[image]

For a different $f(r)$ this kind of [asymptotic inversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251068/asymptotic-inversion-of-expintegralei-function) can be done using `InverseSeries` command, but here it returns unevaluated.

Background [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705378/smallest-value-of-d-such-that-frac-left-sum-i-1d-i-p-right2-sum) on math.SE

Comment: The answer is `f[r_] = Log[2 + Sqrt[2]] r - EulerGamma + (EulerGamma^2/2 + StieltjesGamma[1])/r + (-2 EulerGamma^3 - 6 EulerGamma StieltjesGamma[1] - 3 StieltjesGamma[2])/(6 r^2)` plus higher-order terms; but I have no idea how to do it in Mathematica in a concide way.

Comment: @Roman interesting! For $r\to \infty$, only the first two terms matter, how did you get them?

Comment: (1) Is the $g(x,z)$ in the edit at the top the same specific function in the previous question coded by `g[x, z]`? (Note `AsymptoticSolve[]` is the function that does what you ask in the edit, only it is not robust enough to handle all cases and not `g[x, z]` unfortunately. Probably nothing can handle all cases.) (2) A new question should not supersede an old Q&A but be posted as new question (unless the old Q&A didn't get any answers).

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, it's the same, moved the edit into separate question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285711/automatically-obtaining-asymptotics-for-implicitly-functions-involving-zeta-log). Agreed on general intractability, but only special forms of $g$ in the new question are important to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step way to discover [@Roman's first two terms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285645/getting-a-series-expansion-for-implicitly-defined-function#comment711192_285645):

```
g[r_, x_] = 
  Log[2 (-(E^x)^(-1/r) r + Zeta[1 + 1/r])^2 Zeta[2 (1 + 1/r)]] - 
   Log[Zeta[
       1 + 1/r]^2 (-((E^x)^(1 - 2 (1 + 1/r))/(-1 + 2 (1 + 1/r))) + 
       Zeta[2 (1 + 1/r)])];
```

*Dominant term:* Use a graph to get rough idea. There seems to be a linear relationship between $r=1/\rho$ and $x=1/\xi$ at infinity:

```
ContourPlot[g[1/ρ, 1/ξ] == 0,
 {ρ, 0, 1/10}, {ξ, 0, 1/10}]
```

[image]

Taking $x=ur$ as an ansatz, solve for $u$ at infinity:

```
Limit[g[r, u r], r -> Infinity, Assumptions -> u > 0]
Solve[% == 0 && u > 0, u]

Log[2 E^(-2 u) (-1 + E^u)^2]

{{u -> Log[2 + Sqrt[2]]}}
```

*Constant term:* Again let's graph using the dominant term plus a variable for the remainder:

```
ContourPlot[g[1/ρ, (Log[2 + Sqrt[2]])/ρ + ξ] == 0,
 {ρ, 0, 1/10}, {ξ, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

The constant looks negative, around -0.57.... Let's solve for it at infinity:

```
Limit[g[r, (Log[2 + Sqrt[2]]) r - c] r, r -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> c > 0]
Solve[% == 0, c]
(*
2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]) (-c + EulerGamma)
{{c -> EulerGamma}}
*)
```

Putting it together,

```
x = (Log[2 + Sqrt[2]]) r - EulerGamma + ...
```

Comment: Aha thanks. That seems like a lot of work though, I was wondering if there's a way to adjust the following command to make it work `InverseSeries@Series[g[r, x], {r, \[Infinity], 1}]`

Comment: That's exactly what I meant when I said that "I have no idea how to do it in Mathematica in a concise way." Ideally, [`AsymptoticSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve.html) should do this very trick; but it doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Very interesting answer: Calculating the constant part , why did you take the limit `g[r,...] *r`  (not only `g[r,...] ` ) ? Thanks

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The asymptotic expansion of `g[r,x]` should have the form `a r + b + c/r + ...`, and for the solution for `x`, the coefficients should vanish. When we substitute the partial expansion of the solution for `x`, the expansion of `g` should become `0*r + 0 + c1 / r + ...`. I wanted to recover the coefficient `c1` and solve `c1 == 0`. Thus `r * g[r,...]` has the expansion `c1 + d1/r + e1/r^2 +...`, and the limit at infinity is `c1`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Clever, thanks. I tried unsuccesfully to  evaluate the third term of the asymptotic expansion

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Try `lim = Limit[g[r, (Log[2 + Sqrt[2]]) r - EulerGamma + c/r] r^2, r -> Infinity, Assumptions -> c > 0];
Solve[lim == 0, c]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your helpful support