# Asymptotic inversion of $f(t)$=Root$((1-y)^{2 t+1} (2 t y+y+1)-1/1000)$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have $f(t)$ defined as the root of the following equation for fixed $t$

$$(1-y)^{2 t+1} (2 t y+y+1)-\frac{1}{1000}$$

What is an elegant way to get an expression for the inverse of $f(t)$ in the large $t$ regime?

Approach below calls `Solve` on first 2 terms of Taylor series expansion, but it's far off and adding more terms doesn't help.

```
func = (1 - y)^(1 + 2 t) (1 + y + 2 t y) - 1/1000;
solve := y /. FindRoot[func, {y, 1/(2 t)}];
approxSolve = y /. First@Solve[Normal@Series[func, {y, 0, 2}] == 0, y];
LogLogPlot[{solve, approxSolve}, {t, 10, 30}]
```

[image]

Background [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722368/showing-int-01-x1-x2t-mathrmdx-concentrates-around-frac12t) on math.SE

A similar kind of task was solved by Roman/Michael E2 using mostly-manual approach described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285652/217), I'm interested in automating it for common use-cases.

Comment: Does looking at the plot of the root for discrete values of t help at all? (I only look at the first value of y generated by `Solve` in each case
`ListLinePlot[Table[y /. Solve[func == 0, y][[1]], {t, 1, 40}]]` 

I think I am misunderstanding the question and will have to look at it again tomorrow morning with fresh eyes, and maybe I will understand more clearly.

Comment: Reducing `y` to only be on the `PositiveReals` generates one solution set (there's another solution set on the `NegativeReals` (which I plotted in my last comment), and the number of complex solutions grows linearly with integer `t`:

`ListLinePlot[
 Flatten@Table[y /. Solve[func == 0, y, PositiveReals], {t, 1, 200}]]`

This is much faster (I go up to t=200) because mma doesn't have to calculate all the complex roots, just the one root on the positive reals. I still am not sure if this is actually helpful for you or not

Comment: Are you looking to find $t(y)$ or $y(t)$?  Your question seems to be asking about the former but your code seems to be finding the latter.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert there are 3 quantities at play, $t$, $y$ and $0$. For a fixed $t$ I define $f(t)$ as value of $y$ that makes the expression $0$. Now I want the inverse of $f(t)$, let me know if there's a more clear/concise way to phrase this task

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for an asymptotic expression for $t$ as a function of $y$. So why not start with a `Solve`? (I'm using $z=1/1000$)

```
Assuming[0 < y < 1 && z > 0,
  Solve[(1 - y)^(1 + 2 t) (1 + y + 2 t y) - z == 0, t] // FullSimplify]

(*    {{t -> 1/2 (-1 - 1/y + ProductLog[((1-y)^(1/y) z Log[1-y])/y]/Log[1-y])}}    *)
```

There is a warning emitted that `ProductLog` is a multi-valued function and we might end up on the wrong branch. Indeed, we need to modify the `ProductLog` manually to get on the $k=-1$ branch:

```
tt[y_, z_] = 1/2 (-1 - 1/y + ProductLog[-1, ((1-y)^(1/y) z Log[1-y])/y]/Log[1-y]);
Plot[tt[y, 1/1000], {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

A large-$t$ expression is found by series-expansion around $y=0$:

```
Series[tt[y, z], {y, 0, 0}]

(*    (-1 - ProductLog[-1, -(z/E)])/(2 y) +
      1/4 (-2 + ProductLog[-1, -(z/E)]) +
      O[y]^1                                   *)
```

Concretely, for $z=0.001$:

```
% /. z -> 0.001
(*    4.61671/y - 3.05835 + O[y]^1    *)
```

## update: without `Solve`

Ideally, [`AsymptoticSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve.html) would solve this problem:

```
AsymptoticSolve[(1 - y)^(1 + 2 t) (1 + y + 2 t y) - z == 0, t -> ∞, y -> 0]
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

If we have an idea of the relationship between $y$ and $t$, gleaned either from numerical experiments or from staring at the formula hard enough and realizing that $(1-y)^{2t}$ can only be finite if $t\propto1/y$, then we can try $t(y)=a/y+b+c y+d y^2+\ldots$ and find the coefficients $a,b,c,d,\ldots$:

```
Series[(1 - y)^(1 + 2 t) (1 + y + 2 t y) - z /. 
  t -> a/y + b + c y + d y^2, {y, 0, 3}] // FullSimplify

(*    ((1 + 2 a) E^(-2 a) - z) -
      a (3 + 2 a + 4 b) E^(-2 a) y +
      1/6 (6 a^3 - 6 (1 + b) (1 + 2 b) + a^2 (7 + 24 b) + 4 a (-1 + 3 b + 6 b^2 - 6 c)) E^(-2 a) y^2 +
      1/6 (-2 a^4 + a^3 (1 - 12 b) + 8 b (1 + b) (1 + 2 b) - 6 (3 + 4 b) c + a^2 (6 + 4 (1 - 6 b) b + 24 c) + a (2 b (11 + 6 b - 8 b^2 + 24 c) + 3 (1 + 4 c - 8 d))) E^(-2 a) y^3 +
      O[y]^4                                       *)
```

All these terms must be equal to zero for the whole expression to be zero. The first term gives us the value of $a$, then the second gives us the value of $b$, then… etc. until we have all terms of the series-expansion of $t(y)$. In principle, this is precisely what `AsymptoticSolve` is supposed to do. Let's do it manually:

```
Solve[Table[SeriesCoefficient[(1 - y)^(1 + 2 t) (1 + y + 2 t y) - z /.
                              t -> a/y + b + c y + d y^2, {y, 0, n}] == 0,
            {n, 0, 3}],
      {a, b, c, d}]

(* Warnings about ProductLog branches, see above *)

(*    {{a -> 1/2 (-1 - ProductLog[-(z/E)]),
        b -> 1/4 (-2 + ProductLog[-(z/E)]),
        c -> 1/48 (3 + 2 ProductLog[-(z/E)] - 3/(1 + ProductLog[-(z/E)])),
        d -> 1/96 (3 + 2 ProductLog[-(z/E)] - 3/(1 + ProductLog[-(z/E)]))}}    *)
```

With

```
% /. ProductLog[u_] -> ProductLog[-1, u]
```

we can fix the `ProductLog` branch problems.

Comment: How could one find the asymptotic solution without knowing explicit solution `t->...`? I tried `Asymptotic[(1 - y)^(1 + 2 t) (1 + y + 2 t y) - z,y->0] == 0` without success

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't know. None of the [`AsymptoticSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve.html) combinations I've tried gave anything useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The human brain still has an advantage...

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm learning a lot from your detailed answers + the background/intuition that you provide. One question -- how did you know that you need to take the $-1$ branch of `ProductLog`?

Comment: Try all the branches and see which one fits! Only the –1 and 0 branches are ever of practical interest though because the other branches are complex-valued.

Answer (score 4):

First defining `func` as in your question:

```
func[y_, t_] = (1 - y)^(1 + 2 t) (1 + y + 2 t y) - 1/1000;
```

Note that `Limit[func[(k/t, t], t -> Infinity]` approaches a numerical value:

```
lim = Limit[func[(k/t, t], t -> Infinity]

(*-(1/1000) + (E^(-2/k) (2 + k))/k*)
```

Now solve for k s.t. `lim==0`. There's two Real k solutions, let's just solve for the positive one:

```
kVal = First@SolveValues[lim == 0, k, PositiveReals]

(*1/2 (-1 - ProductLog[-1, -(1/(1000 E))])*)
```

And then confirm this value goes to 0 for large t:

```
Limit[func[kVal/t, t], t -> Infinity]
(*0*)
```

So `y = kVal/t` produces a root for `func[y,t]` for large `t`.

Comment: Nice. So the lesson is -- for $y$ defined implicitly as solution $f(y,x)=0$, if you think it asymptotically linear, can get the asymptotic slope from the limiting value of $f(C x, x)$