# Asymptotics for implicit functions involving Zeta, Log, ExpIntegralEi

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

**Edit** Roman describes how to automate asymptotic inversion for problems of the form below under "without Solve" section of this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286794/217)

I'm interested in a streamlined way of obtaining asymptotic series expansions for equations defined implicitly as $x$ satisfying $$g(x,z)=y$$

With special cases below arising in analysis of gradient descent:

- $f_1(z)$ defined as $x$ such that $g(x,z)=0$ (solved manually [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285652/217))
- $f_2(y)$ defined as $x$ such that $g(x,0)=y$ (solved manually [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/251288/217))

Code below goes over the relevant kinds of $g$ and manually-derived asymptotics, but it would be nice to them obtained automatically, so that small variations of $g$ would be automatically supported.

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
g[x_, z_] = 
  Log[2 (-(E^x)^(-1/z) z + Zeta[1 + 1/z])^2 Zeta[2 (1 + 1/z)]] - 
   Log[Zeta[
       1 + 1/z]^2 (-((E^x)^(1 - 2 (1 + 1/z))/(-1 + 2 (1 + 1/z))) + 
       Zeta[2 (1 + 1/z)])];
f1[z0_] := 
  With[{z = SetPrecision[z0, Infinity]}, 
   x /. FindRoot[g[x, z], {x, 1}]];

faLarge[z_] = 
  Log[2 + Sqrt[2]] z - 
   EulerGamma + (EulerGamma^2/2 + StieltjesGamma[1])/
    z + (-2 EulerGamma^3 - 6 EulerGamma StieltjesGamma[1] - 
      3 StieltjesGamma[2])/(6 z^2);

Plot[{f1[z], faLarge[z]}, {z, 1, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"z", "y"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"original", "large-z"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black, Dashed}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Solutions to g(x,z)=0"]

E1[x_] := -ExpIntegralEi[-x]; (*https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2#E1*)
g[x_, z_] := -ExpIntegralEi[-x];

f2[y_] := x /. First@Flatten@Solve[{g[x, 0] == y, x > 0}, x];
faSmall[y_] := -Log[y] - Log[-Log[y]] - (Log[-Log[y]] - 1)/Log[y];
faLarge[y_] := 
  Exp[-y - EulerGamma] + Exp[-2 y - 2 EulerGamma] + 
   5/4 Exp[-3 y - 3 EulerGamma];
Plot[{f2[y], faSmall[y], faLarge[y]}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Solutions to g(x,0)=y", 
 PlotLegends -> {"Original", "small-y", "large-y"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"y", "x"}]
```